# Run JavaScript on an SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to run some JavaScript on an SSRS report to be able to add in extra functionality.
I have found I can create a hyperlink action to run JavaScript.

```
="javascript:void(console.log('hello world'))"
```

But I would like to have the script run when the report loads, and using an action requires the user to click something first.

At the moment I think I can get this working by making a header section that looks like the report parameter section and adding an image of the view report button that has an action to run the JavaScript, but would there be an easier way to get the JavaScript to run on page load?

I though I might be able to add a fake image and set a script in the onerror attribute, but couldn't find a way to set that either.

The main feature I am trying to add is "copy to clipboard buttons" with svg icons.

Comment: As I know,SSRS is designed for server-side processing and rendering, and it does not provide built-in support for client-side scripting!

Answer (score 0):

as I told you in comments, it does not provide built-in support for client-side scripting,but you can try to use the `window.onload` event to trigger your JS code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        console.log('Hello world');
           //your additional JS code
       };
</script>
```

to do this, first of all create a custom HTML placeholder in your SSRS report and then put above code,in a section of your report that is rendered on every page, like header or footer of your page,so when you viewing your report, the JS code in the custom HTML placeholder will be executed on page load!

and about "copy to clipboard" buttons with SVG icons,you can use JS libraries like `Clipboard.js` to simplify the process of copying text to the clipboard!

Comment: SSRS only interprets a limited number of HTML tags as styles and the other html tags are striped, so the above does not work. If you think you have a way to get the script tag  to not be filtered out when loading into a SSRS report then please give me some more details about how you have got that working and I'll see if I can get that to work for my report.